# subsampling formula skipgram NLP

Tags: nlp, word2vec, subsampling

I'm studying how to implement a Skip-Gram model using Pytorch, I follow this [tutorial](https://naturale0.github.io/2021/02/08/understanding-skip-gram#pytorch-implementation), in the subsampling part the author used this formula:

```
import random
import math

def subsample_prob(word, t=1e-3):
    z = freq[word_to_ix[word]] / sum_freq
    return (math.sqrt(z/t) + 1) * t/z

words_subsample = [w for w in words if random.random() < subsample_prob(w)]
```

where `z` variable is the proportion of counts of a certain word by the total of words in the corpus. my doubt is that depending on the proportion of words this formula gives a result greater than one, then the word is always added to the sub sample corpus, **shouldn't it return a value between zero and one?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frequent-word downsampling option ('subsampling') introduced in the original word2vec (as a `-sample` argument) indeed applies downsampling *only* to a small subset of the very-most-frequent words. (And, given the 'tall head'/Zipfian distributions of words in natural-language texts, that's plenty.)

Typical values leave most words *fully sampled*, as reflected in this formula by a sampling-probability greater-than `1.0`.

So: there's no error here. It's how the original word2vec implementation, and others, interpret the `sample` parameter. Most words are exempt from any thinning, but some of the most-common words are heavily dropped. (But, there's still plenty of their varied usage examples in the training set – and indeed spending *fewer* training updates redundantly on those words lets *other* words get better vectors, facing less contention/dilution from overtraining of common words.)